# Form submits multiple times with one button click, running the related action="" script multiple times

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm working on an inventory management system for my work, and the idea is that when we need to order something it's status is set to 'order' in the mySQL database which contains all of our inventory items. We have an 'Order Queue' page that displays all of the things that need ordered. The twist is that we need two different tables for each supplier: one for Purchase Orders and one for Request for Quotes (e.g. buying raw material isn't always a constant price, so a PO and RFQ need a different format). Then for each supplier table there is a submit button that says "Push *supplier name* PO/RFQ".

Pressing this button takes you to a second page which creates the PO and sends the email to the supplier. I know this isn't the issue here because regardless of what is in this script it will run three times when the button is pressed.

Here's some code:

```
$suppTable = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `suppliers` WHERE (`user` = '" . $user_login . "')");
```

This creates the array storing all the supplier info, and is all correct.

```
<div class="trackheader" style="border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px; border: 2px solid #CC3333;">
    <h3 style="color:white !important; margin-left: 10px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">Display:</h3>
</div>
<div class="trackcont3" style="border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px; border: 2px solid #CC3333; margin-bottom:20px;">
    <form action="" method="POST" id="rec">
        <?php
        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($suppTable)){
            echo "<input type='checkbox' id='" . $row1['name'] . "' name='" . $row1['name'] . "' value='" . $row1['name'] . "' onchange='this.form.submit()'";
            if(isset($_POST['' . $row1['name'] . ''])){ 
                echo "checked='checked'"; 
            }
            echo ">";
            echo "<label for='" . $row1['name'] . "'>" . $row1['name'] . "</label>";
        }
        ?>   
    </form>
</div>
```

Please ignore the inline CSS - this will get added to the stylesheet once this actually works...
This is a pretty straightforward snippet: it creates display toggles for each supplier in the database so that they don't all show up at once.

Now for the fun stuff:

```
<?php
$loopTable = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `suppliers` WHERE (`user` = '" . $user_login . "')");  //this creates another array with each supplier tied to the user account
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($loopTable)){                                                        //this while loop creates two tables for each supplier: one with items that need to be ordered in a PO and another table for RFQ
        if(isset($_POST['' . $row2['name'] . ''])){                                                       //controls display from the above form
                $display['' . $row2['name'] . ''] = "block";
            } else {
                $display['' . $row2['name'] . ''] = "none";
            }
echo "<div style='display:" . $display['' . $row2['name'] . ''] . " ;'>";
            echo "<div class='trackheader' style='border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px; border: 2px solid #CC3333;'>
                        <h3 style='color:white !important; margin-left: 10px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;'>" . $row2['name'] . " PO</h3>
                    </div>";
            echo "<div class='trackcont2'><table style='width:100%; !important'><tbody style='width:100%; !important'>
                    <tr style='width:100% !important;'>
                        <th style='width:16.6%;'><h3 style='color:grey !important;'>ALEX ID</th>
                        <th style='width:16.6%;'><h3 style='color:grey !important;'>Description</th>
                        <th style='width:16.6%;'><h3 style='color:grey !important;'>Supplier P/N</th>
                        <th style='width:16.6%;'><h3 style='color:grey !important;'>Order QTY</th>
                        <th style='width:16.6%;'><h3 style='color:grey !important;'>Price</th>
                        <th style='width:16.6%;'><h3 style='color:grey !important;'>Total</th>
                    </tr>";
                $i = 0;
                $listTablePO = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `inventory` WHERE (`user` = '" . $user_login . "') AND (`supplier` = '" . $row2['name'] . "') AND (`status` = 'order') AND (`method` = 'PO')"); //this creates an array with all database items from the appropriate supplier which need ordered (and go in the PO table)
                $total = 0; //tallies a running total of the price
                while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($listTablePO)){ //this while loop creates the table of all parts that need ordered and their necessary info
                    if($i % 2 == 0){
                        echo "<tr class='odd' style='text-align: center;'>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<tr class='even' style='text-align: center;'>";
                    }
                                echo "<td>" . $row3['part_name'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row3['description'] . "</td>";
                                if($row3['order_link'] == null){
                                    echo "<td>" . $row3['supplier_part_no'] . "</td>";
                                } else {
                                    echo "<td><a href='" . $row3['order_link'] . "' target='_blank'>" . $row3['supplier_part_no'] . "</a></td>";
                                }
                                if($row['order_override'] == 0){
                                    echo "<td>" . $row3['order_qty'] . "</td>";
                                    $qty = $row3['order_qty'];
                                } else {
                                    echo "<td>" . $row3['order_override'] . "</td>";
                                    $qty = $row3['order_override'];
                                }
                                echo "<td>$" . sprintf('%.2lf', $row3['price']) . "</td>";
                                $total = ($total + ($qty * $row3['price']));
                                echo "<td>$" . sprintf('%.2lf', $total) . "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        $i++; 
                    }
            echo "</tbody></table></div>
                    <form action='/po-mailing/' method='POST' name='" . $row2['name'] ."PO'>
                        <input type='hidden' value='" . $row2['name'] . "' name='PO' id='PO'></input>
                        <button type='submit' class='addbutton' style='margin-top: -20px !important; margin-bottom: 20px;'>Push " . $row2['name'] . " PO</button>
                    </form>
            </div>"; //the above snippet handles creating the appropriate form and submit button. All this needs to do is route to the appropriate page (/po-mailing/) and pass the correct supplier name. 
                     //From there I can get all the necessary info from the SQL database and don't need to pass any other info through the form.
                     //I suspect this is where my issue lies, but all I need is an individual Push PO button for each supplier that directs to /po-mailing/ and passes the supplier info to the page. The problem here is it is doing it three times...
```

The next code is basically the same as above but for the RFQ table. Skip this part

```
// the same code is essentially repeated for RFQ for each supplier with minor format changes (it is also irrelevant as I have only been testing with the PO side)
            echo "<div style='display:" . $display['' . $row2['name'] . ''] . " ;'>";
            echo "<div class='trackheader' style='border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px; border: 2px solid #CC3333;'>
                        <h3 style='color:white !important; margin-left: 10px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;'>" . $row2['name'] .  " RFQ</h3>
                    </div>";
            echo "<div class='trackcont2'><table style='width:100% !important;'><tbody style='width:100%; !important'>
                    <tr style='width:100% !important;'>
                        <th style='width:16.6%;'><h3 style='color:grey !important;'>ALEX ID</th>
                        <th style='width:16.6%;'><h3 style='color:grey !important;'>Description</th>
                        <th style='width:16.6%;'><h3 style='color:grey !important;'>Supplier P/N</th>
                        <th style='width:16.6%;'><h3 style='color:grey !important;'>Order QTY</th>
                        <th style='width:16.6%;'><h3 style='color:grey !important;'>Last Price</th>
                        <th style='width:16.6%;'><h3 style='color:grey !important;'>Estimate</th>
                    </tr>";
                    $i = 0;
                    $listTableRFQ = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `inventory` WHERE (`user` = '" . $user_login . "') AND (`supplier` = '" . $row2['name'] . "') AND (`status` = 'order') AND (`method` = 'RFQ')");
                    while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($listTableRFQ)){
                        if($i % 2 == 0){
                            echo "<tr class='odd' style='text-align: center;'>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<tr class='even' style='text-align: center;'>";
                        }
                                echo "<td>" . $row5['part_name'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row5['description'] . "</td>";
                                if($row5['order_link'] == null){
                                    echo "<td>" . $row5['supplier_part_no'] . "</td>";
                                } else {
                                    echo "<td><a href='" . $row5['order_link'] . "' target='_blank'>" . $row5['supplier_part_no'] . "</a></td>";
                                }
                                if($row['order_override'] == 0){
                                    echo "<td>" . $row5['order_qty'] . "</td>";
                                    $qty = $row5['order_qty'];
                                } else {
                                    echo "<td>" . $row5['order_override'] . "</td>";
                                    $qty = $row5['order_override'];
                                }
                                echo "<td>$" . sprintf('%.2lf', $row5['price']) . "</td>";
                                $total = ($total + ($qty * $row5['last_price']));
                                echo "<td>$" . sprintf('%.2lf', $total) . "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        $i++; 
                    }
            echo "</tbody></table></div>
            <form action='/rfq-mailing/' method='POST' id='" . $row2['name'] ."RFQ'>
                <input type='hidden' value='" . $row2['name'] . "' name='" . $row2['name'] . "' id='" . $row2['name'] . "'></input>
                <button type='submit' class='addbutton' style='margin-top: -20px !important; margin-bottom: 20px;'>Push " . $row2['name'] . " RFQ</button>
            </form>
            </div>";
        }
        ?>
```

Hopefully someone can spot where I'm screwing up.. FWIW I'm also using Wordpress as a backend for the system (just an easy way to handle accounts, create pages, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

My wordpress theme appears to load the head of each page multiple times, so the issue wasn't with the code itself. On each load it was submitting the info.

Encasing necessary info in `if(isset($_POST['submitbuttonexample'])){}` fixed the issue.

Comment: "*My wordpress theme appears to load the head of each page multiple times, so the issue wasn't with the code itself*" - that is something that you should also address because that is not good behaviour and could cause more problems down the line.